# Docker container starting failed if it has docker secrets

Tags: docker

I'm trying to run docker stack command using below compose file to understand how docker secret is working.

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  web:
    image: nginxdemos/hello
    secrets:                    # secrets block only for 'web' service
     - my_external_secret
     - my_file_secret

secrets:                        # top level secrets block
  my_external_secret:
    external: true
  my_file_secret:
    file: my_file_secret.txt
```

```
[root@docswarm1 sec]# docker service ps secret_web
ID            NAME              IMAGE             NODE       DESIRED STATE  CURRENT STATE                    ERROR                             PORTS
nafmyftzajlc  secret_web.1      nginxdemos/hello  docswarm1  Running        Starting less than a second ago                              
g0v9qlyc4xlq   \_ secret_web.1  nginxdemos/hello  docswarm2  Shutdown       Failed 22 seconds ago            "starting container failed: Re…"
a5p42laspx6t   \_ secret_web.1  nginxdemos/hello  docswarm3  Shutdown       Failed 35 seconds ago            "starting container failed: Re…"
9711qr1w7yps   \_ secret_web.1  nginxdemos/hello  docswarm1  Shutdown       Failed 16 seconds ago            "starting container failed: Re…"
18rskne1f13j   \_ secret_web.1  nginxdemos/hello  docswarm1  Shutdown       Failed 34 seconds ago            "starting container failed: Re…"
[root@docswarm1 sec]#
```

Unfortunately i'm getting below error

```
"Status": {
            "Timestamp": "2019-12-30T10:07:23.777012653Z",
            "State": "failed",
            "Message": "starting",
            "Err": "starting container failed: RemoveSecretsPath failed: remove /var/lib/docker/containers/be1fb75c79b4c44927569629cb64bb58b4ac24bda960e15e25c2ae3198eecf39/secrets/my_file_secret: read-only file system",
            "ContainerStatus": {
                "ContainerID": "be1fb75c79b4c44927569629cb64bb58b4ac24bda960e15e25c2ae3198eecf39",
                "ExitCode": 128
            },
            "PortStatus": {}
        },
        "DesiredState": "shutdown",
```

Please find the additional details

```
[root@docswarm1 ~]# df '/var/lib/docker/containers'
Filesystem            1K-blocks    Used Available Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/rhel-root   8374272 6781368   1592904  81% /var/lib/docker/containers


[root@docswarm1 ~]# cd /var/lib/docker/containers
[root@docswarm1 containers]# touch test.log
[root@docswarm1 containers]# ls -lhrt test.log
-rw-r--r--. 1 root root 0 Dec 30 17:00 test.log
[root@docswarm1 containers]#
```

Comment: what user are you running your docker commands as? Error message makes it sound like that user doesn't have permissions on `/var/lib/docker/containers/be1fb75c79b4c44927569629cb64bb58b4ac24bda960e15e25c2ae3198eecf39/secrets/my_file_secret`

Comment: Regardless of what user is running the docker *client*, the server always run as `root`. It is unlikely that this is a user permission issue. The error ("read-only filesystem") does not suggest a permissions problem.

Comment: I'm running as root user

Comment: ah, yep, good point @larsks. Try running `df '/var/lib/docker/containers'` and `mount | grep '/var'` and post the output. Also see if you can manually create/remove files under `var/lib/docker/containers`

Comment: @Z4-tier pasted outputs in description bottom.mount | grep '/var' is huge output and not able to paste that

Comment: [root@docswarm1 ~]# mount | grep '/var'
    sunrpc on /var/lib/nfs/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
    /dev/mapper/rhel-root on /var/lib/docker/containers type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)
    /dev/mapper/rhel-root on /var/lib/docker/overlay2 type xfs (rw,relatime,seclabel,attr2,inode64,noquota)